# Is there a way to prevent caching of certain URLs?

Tags: jquery, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, caching, tokenize

I have an auto complete box on my site. I'm using [Tokeninput](http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/). When there isn't a result I have users click a link to add it. The problem is that if they've already typed the exact query that's already been cached, so they have to refresh the page to see the result in the drop down. Is there anyway to prevent caching of certain ajax calls?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the `cache` option in [`jQuery.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to `false`. This will prevent the caching of AJAX calls. It works by adding a new query-string parameter called `_`, which is set to the current timestamp.

Answer (score 2):

Add a unique query parameter onto the end of the URL being requested.  Usually this is done with a random number or time stamp.  I prefer a time stamp.

```
function makeURLUnique(url) {
    var parm = "unique=" + Date.now();    // get timestamp in milliseconds
    if (url.indexOf("?") == -1) {
        parm = "?" + parm;                // no question mark, add one
    } else if (!url.match(/\?$/)) {
        parm = "&" + parm;                // no question mark at the end, must be other parms
    }
    return(url + parm);
}
```

---

If you are using jQuery to fetch the URL, you can use a jQuery option to turn caching off that will do exactly what is described above, but do it automatically for you:

```
 $.ajax(yourURL, {cache: false}).then(...);
```